# how to read file in hex format

Tags: java, hex

I have a file which I have to read from my JAVA code. I can open file in HEX editor, then content is '00 01 00 00' in the opened file from HEX editor.

I want to do following operation from my JAVA code:-
1. read the content. 
2. print it. (It should print as 00 01 00 00).
 So that I can perform some operation on data.

But the problem is,

When I am doing above operation on the file using "FileinputStream" then instead of printing as '00 01 00 00' it is printing as '0 1 0 0' that is every byte is converted into the decimal value.

So is there any way I can perform my desired operation?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "hex byte" - there are just bytes. Unless this is *actually* a text representation? It's not at all clear to me what your "convert into the decimal (00000100)16 = ()10" means either...

Comment: It's not clear if your file is binary or text. Does your file contains strings of 0's and 1's (visible in a text editor) or is it a binary file?

Comment: You've confused Jon Skeet. Now the apocalypse can begin.

Comment: Do you have only 0s and 1s? or do you also have 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F?

Comment: @morgano  Yes I have both numbers and alphabets.

Comment: edited question in more understandable format.

Comment: reading seems to work and printing is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java

Comment: Show code. Probable missing a 0 in format: `printf("%02x ", 0xFF & b);`